# Necessary condition for a rearrangement to be sum preserving (DJH Garling, A course in Mathematical Analysis vol 1 exercise 4.5.3 (b))

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose that $\sum_{j} a_j$ is convergent to $s$ and that $\sigma$ is a permutation of $\mathbb N$. Let $m_j=\sup_{k > j} |a_k|$. Suppose that $m_j|\sigma(j)-j| \rightarrow 0$ as $j \rightarrow \infty$. Show that $\sum_j a_{\sigma(j)}$ is convergent to $s$. (Exercise 4.5.3 (b) in the above mentioned textboook)

PS: I am a self learner, currently reading the chapter on Riemann integration. I have this problem on the back of my mind for some time, but haven't the vaguest clue on how to solve it. Hints, and if I am too stupid to understand, full solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Consider the differences of partial sums,

$$
\sum_{j=1}^ka_j-\sum_{j=1}^ka_{\sigma(j)}\;.
$$

Let $i$ be the least integer such that the right-hand sum does not contain $a_i$. Bound the number of terms by which the two sums differ by $2|\sigma(i)-i|$ and the magnitude of each of them by $m_i$. Then show that $i\to\infty$ as $k\to\infty$.

Comment: $\sigma(a_i)$? That can't be right.

Comment: @user171127: You're right of course. Corrected.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see the point. Please elaborate a little. (Definitely such $k_m$ exists regardless of the condition in the exercise: just take $k_m=max_{i<m}\sigma(i)$. Using the condition given, one can find a bound for $k_j$ of the type $k_j=j+\frac{\epsilon}{m_j}$ for all $j \geq j_\epsilon$. Unfortunately, this does not lead me anywhere...)

Comment: @user171127: Sorry, I hadn't thought this through properly. The basic idea was right, but I've edited the answer to make the details come out right. Apologies for the mistakes.